# Insert at a specific index in array

Tags: java, arrays, insert, indexing

So I want to insert a value in a specific index, that mean I would throw exception if the index I want to insert is not exist or bigger than size, otherwise, I would use this method to ensure the capacity of the array is not null:

```
private void ensureCapacity(int size_wanted)
{
  int max_capacity = storage.length;
  if (size_wanted > max_capacity) 
  {
    max_capacity = max_capacity * GROW_FACTOR +1; 
    storage = Arrays.copyOf(storage, max_capacity); // increases array size + copy contents
  } 
}
```

Then at this point, I suppose to extend the array and already made a copy of my original with the increased size already, right?

All I need to do is using a loop and shift everything to the right by one, to leave space for the index I want to insert at, correct?

Comment: Are you trying to build ArrayList?

Comment: I building a dynamic array that mimic arraylist

Comment: ArrayList contains dynamic array implementation you are doing is already there.

Comment: "not exist or bigger than size". You mean `>= size` actually, remembering that indexes are 0-based.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `System.arrayCopy` to move array like that.
but why are you rebuilding existing functionality provided by [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use a loop; you can use the method `System.arraycopy` to move elements within an array. It correctly handles overlapping ranges:

```
System.arraycopy(storage, insertPos, storage, insertPos+1, oldSize - insertPos);
```

Comment: But then again I cant put the last 2 argument inside, since I cant change an already prep method.

Comment: @RyokoNela - _After_ calling `ensureCapacity`, call `System.arraycopy` (using whatever variable names you are using). Then you assign the new value to the slot that was just created: `storage[insertPos] = insertValue;`.